# Making ScriptableObject inpersistent in game mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

Right now, when I change the value of a field in ScriptableObject in game mode, back to editor, the change is still persistent. Any way to make it not persistent( go back to value before playing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone your ScriptableObject on startup.

```
private void Awake()
{
    myScriptableObject = Instantiate(myScriptableObject);
}
```